# GNUPLOT: Show a x value given a y value

Tags: gnuplot

i'm having some problems with gnuplot
I have to draw a cdf function and i'm interested in the values of variable x when F(x) is equal to 0.1 and 0.9
How can I tell Gnuplot to show me on the x axis the value corresponding to a given value on the y value (in my example those values are 0.1 and 0.9)
thanks

Comment: Please show a short script, which shows the CDF you have.

Answer (score 0):

You're basically asking gnuplot to solve an equation. In your particular case, actually two equations: F(x)=0.1 and F(x)=0.9. As far as I know this cannot be done, but I might be wrong. What you can do if you simply want a graphical solution, is make a conditional plot, and ask that when F(x) is very close to 0.1 0.9, gnuplot plots something other than the function.

For example, assume f(x)=x^2 and you want to know "graphically" for which x f(x)=0.1. Then you can request the value abs(f(x) - 0.1) be small, for example < 0.01. Then tell gnuplot to go to zero (just an example!) if this is the case, otherwise plot f(x)=x^2:

```
f(x)=x**2
set xrange [-2:2]
set samples 1000
plot abs(f(x)-1) < 0.01 ? 0 : f(x)
```

Which yields:

[image]

The two peaks that go to zero mark graphically on the x axis the solution to the equation f(x)=0.1. Of course, you need gnuplot to sample this point in order to see a peak. Thus you need to play with `set samples` and `set xrange`.

Answer (score 0):

From your question it is not clear whether you have a function `F(x)` as expression or just a x,y-data file. I assume that your function is monotonic increasing in x and y.

Two solutions come to my mind:

1. via simple linear interpolation
2. via curve fitting

Let's create some test data. For this, let's assume your function is known (as expression) and something like this (check `help norm`):  `F(x) = a*norm(b*x + c)`

Let's take `a = 1; b = 0.8; c = -4`. In the example below, sampling will be only `8`, just for illustration purpose.
You can easily `set samples 200` and you will get the same results as for the curve fitting method below. From gnuplot 5.0 on, you could write the data into a datablock instead of a file on disk.

**Data:** `SO22276755.dat`

```
 0        3.16712e-05
 1.42857  0.002137
 2.85714  0.043238
 4.28571  0.283855
 5.71429  0.716145
 7.14286  0.956762
 8.57143  0.997863
 10       0.999968
```

**Script 1:** (basically works for gnuplot 4.6.0, March 2012)

```
### interpolate x-values
reset

FILE  = "SO22276755.dat"

yis   = '0.10 0.90'
yi(n) = real(word(yis,n))
xis   = ''
xi(n) = real(word(xis,n))

Interpolate(yi) = (x1-x0)/(y1-y0)*(yi-y0) + x0

getXis(xis) = xis.(n=words(xis), n<words(yis) ? yi=real(word(yis,n+1)) : 0, \
              y0<=yi && y1>=yi ? sprintf(" %g",Interpolate(yi)) : '')

set key left top noautotitle
set grid x,y

plot x1=y1=NaN FILE u (x0=x1,x1=$1):(y0=y1,y1=$2,xis=getXis(xis),y1) \
        w l lc rgb "blue" ti "data", \
     '+' u (xi=xi(int($0+1))):(yi=yi(int($0+1))):\
        (sprintf("(%.4g|%.4g)",xi,yi)) every ::0::1 \
        w labels point pt 7 lc rgb "red" right offset -1,0 ti "interpolated"
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Script 2:** (basically works for gnuplot>=4.6.0, March 2012)

With this approach you are fitting your known function `F(x)` to constant lines, i.e. your desired values `0.1` and `0.9`. For this, a file will be created (could be a datablock for gnuplot>=5.0) and it will basically look like this `SO22276755.fit`:

```
 0  0.1
 1  0.1


 0  0.9
 1  0.9
```

```
### interpolate x-values
reset

F(x) = a*norm(b*x+c)     # function

a     = 1
b     = 0.8
c     = -4
yis   = '0.10 0.90'
yi(n) = real(word(yis,n))
xis   = ''
xi(n) = real(word(xis,n))

set key left top noautotitle
set grid x,y

# create fit levels file
LEVELS  = "SO22276755.fit"
set table LEVELS
    set samples 2
    plot for [i=1:words(yis)] '+' u (yi(i))
unset table

xmin = 0
xmax = 10
set xrange[xmin:xmax]
set samples 100
xis = ''
do for [i=1:words(yis)] {
    xi = (xmin+xmax)*0.5   # set start value
    fit F(xi) LEVELS u 1:2 index i-1 via xi
    xis = xis.sprintf(" %g",xi)
}
plot F(x) w l lc rgb "web-green" ti "F(x)", \
     '+' u (xi=xi(int($0+1))):(yi=yi(int($0+1))):(sprintf("(%.4g|%.4g)",xi,yi)) \
         every ::0::1 w labels point pt 7 lc rgb "red" righ offset -1,0 ti "fitted"
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]