# Gnuplot: Find y value for given x value

Tags: gnuplot

I have a set of data points I plot with gnuplot. Know I calculate a value for x and want to find the corresponding y value within the data.

Does anybody know how to manage this with gnuplot?

Comment: Can you please show some example data? Do you want to find an exact match or the closest data point or are you maybe talking about interpolation?

Answer (score 0):

I found kind of a solution [here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32766362/gnuplot-find-x-value-for-given-y)
Basically you have to invert the function you use to calculate `y` (or `x` in the case of the link) and then, thanks to the `sprintf` function, you gate the corresponding value.

## NOTE

Have a look also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22276755/gnuplot-show-a-x-value-given-a-y-value?rq=1) if you did not find the solution at the first link!

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: The Problem is, that I don't have a function but only a set of data points. At the moment there were only a few files where I had to find the matching values so I did it by hand, but I hoped to find a solution to do this automatically with gnuplot so I can handle many files.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is a rather old question, the following solution for interpolation might still be of interest to others.
The code can be simplified depending on whether you are just interested in nearest datapoint or in the interpolated value or whether you want to plot the value as point and/or label.

**Code:**

```
### interpolate between datapoints
reset session

$Data <<EOD
0     0
0.30  0.20
0.60  0.40
0.80  0.80
1    1
EOD

$Data2 <<EOD
1     0
0.80  0.15
0.50  0.30
0.50  0.50
0.30  0.80
0     1
EOD

InterpolY(x,x0,x1,y0,y1) = (x-x0)*(x-x1)<0 || x1-x0==0 ? x1-x0==0 ? (y0+y1)/2 : (y1-y0)/(x1-x0)*(x-x0) +y0 : NaN

set key noautotitle
array Point[1]   # dummy array for plotting a single datapoint

# x-value for interpolation is defined in xp
plot x1=y1=yp=(xp=0.7,NaN) $Data u (x0=x1,x1=$1):(y0=y1,y1=$2, yp==yp ? NaN : yp=InterpolY(xp,x0,x1,y0,y1),y1) w lp pt 7, \
        Point u (xp):(yp) w p pt 7 lc "red", \
        Point u (xp):(yp):(sprintf("(%.2g|%.2g)",xp,yp)) w labels right offset -1,0 lc "red", \
     x1=y1=yp=(xp=0.5,NaN) $Data2 u (x0=x1,x1=$1):(y0=y1,y1=$2, yp==yp ? NaN : yp=InterpolY(xp,x0,x1,y0,y1),y1) w lp pt 7, \
        Point u (xp):(yp) w p pt 7 lc "green", \
        Point u (xp):(yp):(sprintf("(%.2g|%.2g)",xp,yp)) w labels right offset -1,0 lc "green", \
### end of code
```

**Result:** (interpolated values at x=0.7 and x=0.5)

[image]