# How to get a y value for a x coordinate

Tags: gnuplot

In gnuplot, if I have a line curve using some data points and I want to know what value of x(in a line) correspond what value of y(apart from the data file I have). How can I do it in gnuplot?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please give some example data. Do you have unique x-values? Are you talking about interpolation of values?

Comment: @theozh lets say i have these data sets for x and y , x=1,3,5,7 and y=1,9,25,49  . Now i if I plot them in gnuplot they will give a line curve. Now, I want to know what value of y I have at x=2 on this line curve. These data sets are only an example.

Comment: Do you mean some scripted non-interactive mechanism?  If you are looking at the plot interactively, you can position the mouse over the relevant point and read off the current coordinates, and middle-click on it to have the coordinates written to the plot as a label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do linear interpolation with gnuplot.
While plotting the data you assign in a "serial evaluation" (check `help operators binary`, serial evaluation) the previous coordinate to x0,y0 and the current coordinate to x1,y1. Between those you are doing linear interpolation and writing the interpolated value to `yi`. In a second plot command you can plot this value as single value via `'+' u (myX):(yi) every ::0::0 w labels`. Check `help special-filenames`, `help every`, `help labels`.

*edit:* change script to work also for decreasing x-values.

**Script:**

```
### interpolate a value
reset session

$Data <<EOD
 1   1
 3   9
 5  25
 7  49
EOD

xi = 2
Interpolate(xi) = x0==x1 ? (y0+y1)/2. : (y1-y0)/(x1-x0)*(xi-x0) + y0
set key top left noautotitle

plot x1=y1=NaN $Data u (x0=x1,x1=$1):(y0=y1,y1=$2, (x0-xi)*(x1-xi)<=0 ? \
        yi=Interpolate(xi):0, y1) w lp pt 7 lc "red" ti "data", \
     '+' u (xi):(yi):(sprintf("(%g|%g)",xi,yi)) every ::0::0 \
        w labels point pt 7 lc "blue" offset 0,1 ti "interpolated"
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Actually, I noticed too late. There is such a question and answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41563383/7295599