# Gnuplot: highlight specific values

Tags: gnuplot, highlight

In Gnuplot, can I highlight specific values on a linear graph? By highlight", I mean draw the lines from the axis values to a specific point on the graph and print that spot with a dot. I have a few such interesting values. I can "draw" all this manually with "set arrow" etc, but I wonder if there's a built-in mechanism.

[image]

Comment: Is your curve a function or some data from a datafile?

Comment: Datafile, though it does actually create math-looking graphs (lines and curves) :)

Comment: if you have your data in a file and you don't have gnuplot 6.0 for Ethan's solution you could try these workarounds https://stackoverflow.com/a/69466654/7295599 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/73219233/7295599

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT2:** As [@Ethan answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76791613/6113363), there will be a built-in solution since version 6.0. Until then, there is a hand-made solution, if you have a function *f(x)* [left image]:

```
# gnuplot 5.4.4
reset; set grid;

xmin=0
ymin=0

set xrange [xmin:]
set yrange [ymin:]

highlight(x, y, xmin, ymin) \
        = sprintf("set arrow from %f,%f to %f,%f nohead lw 2 lc -1; \
                   set arrow from %f,%f to %f,%f nohead lw 2 lc -1; \
                   set label at %f,%f point pt 7 lc -1 ps 2; ", xmin, y, x, y, x, ymin, x, y, x, y)
        
f(x)=0.5*x+0.2
        
eval highlight(4,2.2,xmin,ymin)
eval highlight(6,f(6),xmin,ymin)

plot f(x) notitle
```

[image: Example]
[image: Example of extended answer]

**EDIT:** as the OP asked for a solution which uses data points from a file instead of a function, there is a possible solution [right image]:

```
# gnuplot 5.4.4
reset; set colors classic; set grid

datafile='007_d.dat'

xmin=0
ymin=0

set xrange [xmin:]
set yrange [ymin:]

highlight(x, y, xmin, ymin) \
        = sprintf("set arrow from %f,%f to %f,%f nohead lw 2 lc -1; \
                   set arrow from %f,%f to %f,%f nohead lw 2 lc -1; \
                   set label at %f,%f point pt 7 lc -1 ps 2; ", xmin, y, x, y, x, ymin, x, y, x, y)

byx(x) \
        = sprintf("plot datafile u ($1 == %f ?$1:1/0):2; \
                  eval highlight(GPVAL_DATA_X_MIN,GPVAL_DATA_Y_MIN,xmin,ymin)", x)

byy(y) \
        = sprintf("plot datafile u ($2==2.7?$1:1/0):2; \
                  eval highlight(GPVAL_DATA_X_MIN,GPVAL_DATA_Y_MIN,xmin,ymin)", y)
                  
eval highlight(4,2.2,xmin,ymin)
eval byx(6)
eval byy(2.7)

plot datafile w lp ps 2 notitle
```

**NOTE:** you can use *datafile* as an extra parameter for *byx()* / *byy()* ofcourse; also you can play with *xmin* amd *ymin* as your particular needs.

**ATTENTION:** the code assumes, that you have unique x-y data pairs.

Comment: It works, I added "front" at the end of the "set label" line, as I want the dot on top of the graph. My data come from a file, not a math function. Is there a way to get the y value for a given x, so that "highlight" would automatically retrieve it for a given x?

Comment: I have edited the answer for using data file.

Answer (score 3):

> My data come from a file, not a math function. Is there a way to get
> the y value for a given x, so that "highlight" would automatically
> retrieve it for a given x?

Gnuplot version 6 will support this.  It has been in the development branch for a while now. If you are willing to build from source or try the test build, it is available in the release candidate for 6.0 available from the gnuplot home site on SourceForge.

Full documentation and example figure here:
http://gnuplot.info/docs_6.0/loc4436.html

Short example:

```
plot DATA using 1:2 smooth cnormal watch y=0.25 watch y=0.5 watch y=0.75
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different solution:

- using a rectangle ranging from outside the graph (-1,-1) to the point(s) of interest
- using a datablock and a for loop placing lines from the datapoint o the left and the bottom axes and a point and a label close to the point

If you don't have a function but a data file, you need to adapt the script.

**Script:**

```
### mark special points on a function
reset session

f(x) = x**2 + 4*x + 1

$Marks <<EOD
-5
 7
EOD

do for [i=1:|$Marks|] {
    set obj i rect from graph -1, graph -1 to first $Marks[i], first f($Marks[i]) fs empty
    set label i at first $Marks[i], first f($Marks[i]) sprintf("(%g,%g)",real($Marks[i]), f($Marks[i])) point pt 7 lc "red"  right offset 0,1
}

plot f(x) w l lc "blue"
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you could simplify this by replacing xmin with GPVAL_X_MIN and ymin with GPVAL_Y_MIN.

These are builtin variables.

```
reset
set grid

highlight(x, y) \
        = sprintf("set arrow from %f,%f to %f,%f nohead lw 2 lc -1; \
                   set arrow from %f,%f to %f,%f nohead lw 2 lc -1; \
                   set label at %f,%f point pt 7 lc -1 ps 2; ", GPVAL_X_MIN, y, x, y, x, GPVAL_Y_MIN, x, y, x, y)
        
f(x)=0.5*x+0.2
        
eval highlight(4,2.2)
eval highlight(6,f(6))

plot f(x) notitle
replot
```

The replot is there because the builtin variables are not set until you plot once.